# Offline caching precdence?

Tags: html, offline-caching

I'm trying to figure out if all pages should include the manifest attribute.  From what I've seen, pages that have the manifest attribute specified and that serve dynamic data won't display the most up-to-date data because it's served up from the appCache.  If I specify the pages that display dynamic data in the NETWORK section, those pages will still be served up from the appCache.  The documentation I've read isn't clear on precedence.  Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a file ends up in the application cache it will always be served from the application cache.  Don't put references to the manifest file in dynamic pages as they will then be added to the cache, the only way you will then be able to get the browser to load a new version of the page is to update the manifest file.

For more details on this and other gotchas have a read of Jake Archibald's recent article [Application Cache is a Douchebag](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/application-cache-is-a-douchebag/).